# How can I merge my app page with a regular page?

Tags: facebook

I recently created an app on Facebook to make sharing on my site easier. The problem is I had created a page prior to this and now want to merge my page with my app page, since I have subscribers on the original page. Is this even possible? I don't want to loose my current subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a merge duplicate pages under the 'resources' section of the page settings.

There's a good article [here](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/08/03/how-to-use-merge-duplicate-pages/) about the process

1. Make sure that the two pages of yours have the exact same name.
2. Make sure that your pages are categorized as Community pages because only Community Pages can be merged.
3. Go to the page you want to keep.
4. Click the Edit Page button in the top right corner.
5. From the left column menu, click Resources.
6. Click the Merge duplicate pages link.
7. A dialogue will show pages you admin that qualify to be merged. Select the page(s) you wish to merge to the page you’re on. If you’re merging a place and a page, they must have the same address information.

Note that when your request has been sent, your application will be reviewed by Facebook team. The review process may take up to 7 days, so be patient. When they have completed, they will notify you via Facebook message. After that, all of the content will be merge, including your fans. You can merge up to 5 pages per time. If you want to merge more, you must submit multiple requests.

Comment: I did this already but there is no merge link... I named both pages with the same title but still didn't get the merge link.

Comment: Updated my answer. Might be a bit more helpful